# lm-sensors not showing information

Tags: fan, temperature, lm-sensors

After running `sensors-detect` and using all default settings, when running `sensors` I do not get a lot of information:

```
schoolbusesc2@desktop:~$ sensors
enp4s0-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
PHY Temperature:  +45.9°C  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +55.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +55.8°C
```

How will I be able to find the:

- Fan speed
- Voltages
- CPU clock speed
- Etc.

Please tell me if you need more information.

Thanks,
Owen

**EDIT:**
Here is `sensors-detect`:

```
schoolbusesc2@desktop:~$ sudo sensors-detect
[sudo] password for schoolbusesc2: 
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# Board: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG CROSSHAIR VIII FORMULA
# Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64
# Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor (23/113/0)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           Success!
    (driver `k10temp')
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               Yes
Found `Nuvoton NCT6798D Super IO Sensors'                   Success!
    (address 0x290, driver `nct6775')
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): yes
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (yes/NO): yes
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Using driver `i2c-piix4' for device 0000:00:14.0: AMD KERNCZ SMBus

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 0 at 0b00 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Client found at address 0x1a
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP400'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No
Client found at address 0x1b
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No
Client found at address 0x52
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)
Client found at address 0x53
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)
Client found at address 0x77
Probing for `Asus Mozart-2'...                              No

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 2 at 0b00 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA GPU I2C adapter (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at a:00.0 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x2a
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM80'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM96080'...             No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D'...                            No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D'...                            No
Probing for `Nuvoton NCT7802Y'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627HF'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627EHF'...                          No
Probing for `Winbond W83627DHG/W83667HG/W83677HG'...        No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.1)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.2)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus ASB100 Bach'...                           No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP400'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP421'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP441'...                   No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95231'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95233'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95241'...             No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1029'...                     No
Probing for `ITE IT8712F'...                                No

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 3 at a:00.0 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 5 at a:00.0 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x58
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7462'...                     No
Probing for `Andigilog aSC7512'...                          No
Client found at address 0x5c
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7462'...                     No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1072'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1073'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1074'...                               No

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at a:00.0 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 7 at a:00.0 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 8 at a:00.0 (i2c-8)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 17h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `nct6775':
  * ISA bus, address 0x290
    Chip `Nuvoton NCT6798D Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
nct6775
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK

schoolbusesc2@desktop:~$
```

Comment: The `sensors-detect` application usually recommends to add/load some kernel drivers. Did you forget to add/load them?

Comment: try running sensors-detect again and answer yes to all questions

Comment: It's not possible to probe devices to get the value of those parameters if your devices don't support them.The output of ```sensors``` in my system just shows the temperature of the CPU cores.Nothing more.

Comment: post the output from `sensors-detect` as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `modprobe nct6775` to load the kernel module, instead of `/etc/init.d/kmod start`.

---

First I have ran into this problem too, and this is how I found your question.
The command recommended by `sensors-detect` at the end does not work as expected, probably because the command will be handled by systemctl (running without proper rights reveals this in an error), and since the `kmod` service is already running, `systemd` won't start or reload it.

That said, if you haven't undone the changes made by `sensors-detect`, *I think* this should already work for you, because you have probably rebooted your system since you made the question.

I'm fairly certain this will work for you too, because `sensors-detect` found the same sensor in my machine as in yours, and after running modprobe, `sensors` now shows a bunch of more sensors as expected.